# Django makemigrations makes new migration files for unchanged model fields

Tags: python, django, migration

What I'm using is as follows, I have defined a custom JSONField type and added a custom validator class to it.

***models.py***

```
json_ctn = JsonField(verbose_name=_('Json'), null=True, blank=True)
```

***fields.py***

```
class JsonField(models.TextField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if kwargs.get('validators'):
            kwargs['validators'].append(JsonValidator())
        else:
            kwargs.update({'validators': [JsonValidator()]})

        super(JsonField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

***validators.py***

```
@deconstructible
class JsonValidator(object):

    error_messages = {
        'wrong_json_code': _('Provided custom value is not a valid JSON string.'),
    }

    def __call__(self, value):
        try:
            json.loads(value)
        except (ValueError, SyntaxError) as err:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages.get('wrong_json_code'))
        return value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

The problem is with everytime I run makemigrations, **even when there is no change in anything**, a new migration is created with the following content :

```
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='whatever',
    name='json_ctn',
    field=PATH.fields.JsonField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Json', validators=[PATH.validators.JsonValidator(), PATH.validators.JsonValidator(), PATH.validators.JsonValidator()]),
),
```

1. Any idea why is this the behavior ? I've even altered the _ *eq* _ to
   always return True, as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#custom-deconstruct-method).
2. Also why JsonValidator() is added 3 times to the
   validators in the migration file ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the duplicate entries because you are appending to the same list each time the field is initialized. It would be better to use the `default_validators` attribute, as [used in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators). You can then remove your `__init__` method.

```
class JsonField(models.TextField):
    default_validators = [validators.validate_slug]
```

Hopefully that will solve the migration issue as well. You might need to create one final migration before it stops changing (or recreate the previous migration that added the json fields).